# Зависает программа с отрисковкой линий (простые часы)

Tags: c#, winforms

Написал простейшие часы, нужно как то сделать автоматическую отрисовку. Если всё повесить на кнопку, вроде работает. Засунул в while, после нескольких секунд программа зависает. Что можно придумать?

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Clock
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public void Animation()
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            Pen red = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);
            Pen black = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
            Pen blue = new Pen(Color.Blue, 2);
            Graphics gPanel = panel1.CreateGraphics();
            int length = 70;
            DateTime date1;
            date1 = DateTime.Now;
            gPanel.Clear(Color.White);
            gPanel.DrawLine(red, new Point(panel1.Height / 2, panel1.Width / 2), new Point((int)(panel1.Height / 2 + length * Math.Cos(date1.Second * 6 * Math.PI / 180 - 90 * Math.PI / 180)), (int)(panel1.Width / 2 + length * Math.Sin(date1.Second * 6 * Math.PI / 180 - 90 * Math.PI / 180))));
            gPanel.DrawLine(blue, new Point(panel1.Height / 2, panel1.Width / 2), new Point((int)(panel1.Height / 2 + length * Math.Cos(date1.Minute * 6 * Math.PI / 180 - 90 * Math.PI / 180)), (int)(panel1.Width / 2 + length * Math.Sin(date1.Minute * 6 * Math.PI / 180 - 90 * Math.PI / 180))));
            gPanel.DrawLine(black, new Point(panel1.Height / 2, panel1.Width / 2), new Point((int)(panel1.Height / 2 + length * Math.Cos(date1.Hour * 30 * Math.PI / 180 - 90 * Math.PI / 180)), (int)(panel1.Width / 2 + length * Math.Sin(date1.Hour * 30 * Math.PI / 180 - 90 * Math.PI / 180))));
            string time = date1.ToString().Split(' ')[1];
            string date = date1.ToString().Split(' ')[0];
            label1.Text = $"{time}\n{date}";
        }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            while (true) Animation();
        }

        private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Заменить `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)` на `await Task.Delay(100)`? Или использовать DispatcherTimer вместо бесконечного цикла?

Comment: Попробовал первый вариант, программа сразу виснет

Comment: Пофиксил, благодарю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Clock
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public void Animation()
        {
            Pen red = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);
            Pen black = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
            Pen blue = new Pen(Color.Blue, 2);
            Graphics gPanel = panel1.CreateGraphics();
            int length = 70;
            DateTime date1;
            date1 = DateTime.Now;
            gPanel.Clear(Color.White);
            gPanel.DrawLine(red, new Point(panel1.Height / 2, panel1.Width / 2), new Point((int)(panel1.Height / 2 + length * Math.Cos(date1.Second * 6 * Math.PI / 180 - 90 * Math.PI / 180)), (int)(panel1.Width / 2 + length * Math.Sin(date1.Second * 6 * Math.PI / 180 - 90 * Math.PI / 180))));
            gPanel.DrawLine(blue, new Point(panel1.Height / 2, panel1.Width / 2), new Point((int)(panel1.Height / 2 + length * Math.Cos(date1.Minute * 6 * Math.PI / 180 - 90 * Math.PI / 180)), (int)(panel1.Width / 2 + length * Math.Sin(date1.Minute * 6 * Math.PI / 180 - 90 * Math.PI / 180))));
            gPanel.DrawLine(black, new Point(panel1.Height / 2, panel1.Width / 2), new Point((int)(panel1.Height / 2 + length * Math.Cos(date1.Hour * 30 * Math.PI / 180 - 90 * Math.PI / 180)), (int)(panel1.Width / 2 + length * Math.Sin(date1.Hour * 30 * Math.PI / 180 - 90 * Math.PI / 180))));
            string time = date1.ToString().Split(' ')[1];
            string date = date1.ToString().Split(' ')[0];
            label1.Text = $"{time}\n{date}";
        }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        async private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            while (true) { await Task.Delay(100); Animation(); }
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```